# making list of float from list and sub list ,also that list callable in another object

Tags: python, string, list

```
 line=[u'2001.0,0.88', u'2001.0,0.56564652', u'2001.0,0.908982970575',
 u'2001.0,0.842525219898', 
u'2001.0,0.909303285534,0.566901413923,0.463373691946']


def parsePoint(line):

A= [list(map(lambda x: round(float(x), 4),i.split(','))) for i in line]

return LabeledPoint(label=A[0],features=A[1:])

B=parsePoint(line)
Z=B.label.take(1)
Y=B.features.take(1)
print Z,Y
```

I want answer this typed

```
z=2001.0,Y=0.88
```

Note -1.round 4 digit  , 
2.making again list for using this purpose [year=x[0],feature=x[1:]]like wise

Comment: thanx sir , for editing question

Comment: Note -1.round 4 digit , 2.making again list for using this purpose [year=x[0],feature=x[1:]]like wise : Please explain this better, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
>>> line=[u'2001.0,0.88', u'2001.0,0.56564652', u'2001.0,0.908982970575', u'2001.0,0.842525219898', u'2001.0,0.909303285534,0.566901413923,0.463373691946']
>>> [list(map(lambda x: round(float(x), 4),i.split(','))) for i in line]
[[2001.0, 0.88], [2001.0, 0.5656], [2001.0, 0.909], [2001.0, 0.8425], [2001.0, 0.9093, 0.5669, 0.4634]]
```

**OR**

```
>>> [list(map(lambda x: float(re.sub(r'(\.\d{4}).*', r'\1', x)),i.split(','))) for i in line]
[[2001.0, 0.88], [2001.0, 0.5656], [2001.0, 0.9089], [2001.0, 0.8425], [2001.0, 0.9093, 0.5669, 0.4633]]
```

Comment: thanks but now my problem not solve , again i am editing my question?using your answer

Comment: @GanpatChoudhary ask this as a new question.